# JSON 'undefined' result

Tags: javascript, json

very new to json.

Ran into a slight bump.

I have a feed that if there is no data for commentnotes, it returns that string as "undefined"

i simply want  to remove the "undefined" text and leave it as empty.

here is my js

```
        document.getElementById("tooltipwrap0").innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:22px; font-weight:600;">' + data.users[0].member + " " + data.users[0].party + "-" + data.users[0].state + "<br/>" + '<span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:300;">' + data.users[0].commentnotes + "";
```

here is a sample of my feed

```
   var data={
"users": [
    {
        "member": "first name",
        "party": "F",
        "state": "Ala.",


    },
```

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You don't have an JSON [string], that's a simple object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to test the existence in a condition, like

```
if ("commentnotes" in data.users[0])
    // append data.users[0].commentnotes to your string
```

However, since the `undefined` value it would yield is falsy you can simply try to get it and use the empty string if there is nothing:

```
data.users[0].commentnotes ? data.users[0].commentnotes : ""
```

which can be shortened to

```
data.users[0].commentnotes || ""
```

Notice that you will have to wrap it in parenthesis when you're using this expression inside the string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(data.users[0].commentnotes || '')` to default to an empty string in case the actual value is falsy or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:22px; font-weight:600;">' + data.users[0].member + " " + data.users[0].party + "-" + data.users[0].state + "<br/>" + '<span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:300;">';

if (data.users[0].commentnotes){
  innerHTML += data.users[0].commentnotes;
}

document.getElementById("tooltipwrap0").innerHTML = innerHTML;
```